# Inject JS variable into a haml template

Tags: ruby, html, haml, local-storage

I'm trying use HTML5 localStorage with a Ruby haml template and need to be able to get the value of localStorage.getItem('myItem') to pass to a java applet (code stripped down):

```
- content_box("MyBox") do
  %object{:classid => "clsid:xxx"}
    %param{:name => "myItem", :value => "javascript:localStorage.getItem('myItem')"}
    %comment
      %EMBED{:myItem => "javascript:localStorage.getItem('myItem')"}
      %noembed
```

Is there a good way to do this? I can do something like:

```
:javascript
  document.write("<param name='myItem' value="+localStorage.getItem('myItem')+">"
```

but that's so ugly!

Note that this is an object I'm embedding, and need the value to be present before document_ready; I cannot select the object and append the value to it on document_ready. The only other way I can think of is to do an ajax submission to make the value a Ruby variable ahead of time, but that's really unnecessary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the only way that works is ugly.

IF your data is stored on the client, creating a server request/page/action just to get the data and pass it back in a different form straight back to the client is uncessessary, and arguably uglier.

Go with using javascript to add the `<param>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

If the object depends on JavaScript anyway, you may as well just write the whole element with JavaScript instead of just the param. Then you can do it on document ready.